# Loop through files in a directory using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

How can I change the following code to look at all the .log files in the directory and not just the one file?

I need to loop through all the files and delete all lines that do not contain "step4" or "step9". Currently this will create a new file, but I'm not sure how to use the `for each` loop here (newbie).

The actual files are named like this: **2013 09 03 00_01_29.log**. I'd like the output files to either overwrite them, or to have the SAME name, appended with "out".

```
$In = "C:\Users\gerhardl\Documents\My Received Files\Test_In.log"
$Out = "C:\Users\gerhardl\Documents\My Received Files\Test_Out.log"
$Files = "C:\Users\gerhardl\Documents\My Received Files\"

Get-Content $In | Where-Object {$_ -match 'step4' -or $_ -match 'step9'} | `
Set-Content $Out
```

Answer (score 505, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\gerhardl\Documents\My Received Files" -Filter *.log | 
Foreach-Object {
    $content = Get-Content $_.FullName

    #filter and save content to the original file
    $content | Where-Object {$_ -match 'step[49]'} | Set-Content $_.FullName

    #filter and save content to a new file 
    $content | Where-Object {$_ -match 'step[49]'} | Set-Content ($_.BaseName + '_out.log')
}
```

Comment: thanks. The BaseName part does not work (version 1) - but I managed by first creating a backup of the full file then making the change to the original file.

Comment: For v1, you can use the following to extract the base name: [io.path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($name)

Comment: If I replace `BaseName` with `FullName` I get what I want.

Answer (score 145):

To get the content of a directory you can use

```
$files = Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\gerhardl\Documents\My Received Files\"
```

Then you can loop over this variable as well:

```
for ($i=0; $i -lt $files.Count; $i++) {
    $outfile = $files[$i].FullName + "out" 
    Get-Content $files[$i].FullName | Where-Object { ($_ -match 'step4' -or $_ -match 'step9') } | Set-Content $outfile
}
```

An even easier way to put this is the `foreach` loop (thanks to @Soapy and @MarkSchultheiss):

```
foreach ($f in $files){
    $outfile = $f.FullName + "out" 
    Get-Content $f.FullName | Where-Object { ($_ -match 'step4' -or $_ -match 'step9') } | Set-Content $outfile
}
```

Comment: This creates one output file named "out.log". How can I create a separate output file for each input file?

Comment: @user2725402 I added an input dependend output file that is named <input file name>out

Comment: not sure what I'm doing wrong but this is not working - I now get no output files (and no errors):  `$files = Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\gerhardl\Documents\My Received Files\"  


$files | Where-Object {
    $outFile = $_.Name + "out"
    Get-Content $_.FullName | Where-Object {
        $_ -match 'step4' -or $_ -match 'step9'
    } | Set-Content $outFile 
}`

Comment: @user2725402 I've rewritten the answer using a for loop.

Comment: okay 2 new issues... this now for some reason does the opposite of the match, i.e. it creates a file with only records NOT containing "step4" or "step9".  Also, it is renaming using "out" as an extension, so files are named "XXX.log.out" - I tried using BaseName but can't get it right.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to remove the negation. Use Where-Object { $_ -match 'step4' -or $_ -match 'step9' } instead.

Comment: You can also do `foreach ($f in Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\gerhardl\Documents\My Received Files\") { ... }`

Comment: or use `ForEach ($f  in $files){...}`

Answer (score 47):

If you need to loop inside a directory recursively for a particular kind of file, use the below command, which filters all the files of `doc` file type

`$fileNames = Get-ChildItem -Path $scriptPath -Recurse -Include *.doc`

If you need to do the filteration on multiple types, use the below command.

`$fileNames = Get-ChildItem -Path $scriptPath -Recurse -Include *.doc,*.pdf`

Now `$fileNames` variable act as an **array** from which you can loop and apply your business logic.

Comment: What bugged me was the omission of hidden and/or system files. To also see them you have to use the `-Force` parameter to Get-ChildItem. See its doc at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7 .

Comment: Note: The Include parameter only works when either the command includes the Recurse parameter or the path leads to the contents of a directory (https://stackoverflow.com/a/41700792)