# Script to get ERROR and WARN lines

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to get all the ERROR and WARN lines to files with the name of an object, like the following:

```
$items = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Test"

foreach ($item in $items)
{
    gci $item *.log* -rec -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
        Select-String "WARN|ERROR" >> "C:\MyDir$item.Name_logTest.txt"
}
```

However, the recursive flag doesn't allow me to go over all folders.

EDIT: Guys, I figured it out. Instead of using "gci $item", I used "gci $item.PSPath"

Comment: Try this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18847145/loop-through-files-in-a-directory-using-powershell

Comment: Please describe us what exactly you want. Maybe provide a simple example.

Comment: In the code I've provided before, I want to get a file for every $item in the directory "C:Test" with the ERRORs and WARNs. The reason I want this is because the folders below the "C:Test" represent the objects I need to extract the info from.

Comment: The answer was not for you Ansgar.

Those ERRORs and WARNs are from a proprietary application.

Answer (score 0):

```
ForEach ($Item in (Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Test" -filter "*.log" -recurse)) {...
```