# How to remove EXIF data from image, but keep the orientation?

Tags: image, orientation, jpeg, exif, exiftool

When I remove the EXIF data from a folder with images with the Windows properties-tool, the orientation (that was already manually changed), is lost. So when I want to place all this pictures on a website, they aren't displayed correctly. The problem is that the size of the folder has increased dramatically at this moment, to change it manually again. So, is there a way to keep the orientation tag when you remove all the EXIF data, in one step?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the command line, you could use [Exiftool](https://exiftool.org) with this command:

```
exiftool -all:all= -tagsFromFile @ -exif:Orientation example.jpg
```

Another thing you could do is rotate the image before uploading.  For example, [Irfanview](http://www.irfanview.com/) has a plugin that will do lossless jpeg rotation for you.

Finally, you can check to see if the website can rotate the image for you.  Sites like Facebook and Imgur have options to rotate the image.

Comment: This is great! Thank you. I prefer this command, as it leaves the ICC profile data intact: `exiftool -geotag= -EXIF= -tagsFromFile @ -exif:Orientation example.jpg`

Comment: Is there a way to do it without preserving the exif data?

Answer (score 6):

I use [Imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php) for this. Quick batch script (linux):

`for f in *.JPG *.jpg; do convert $f -auto-orient $f; done`

withstanding some pain, [you can do similar things with windows Batch](https://ss64.com/nt/for2.html) or (slightly less painful) [Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18847145/loop-through-files-in-a-directory-using-powershell#18848848).

Notice that this only takes care of the orientation, you might still want to remove the rest of the EXIF.

Comment: To remove the rest of the meta data including the EXIF data just add -strip after -auto-orient.

Comment: One thing to take note of is that this is a destructive re-compress.  It will introduce graphic artifacts the more often it is done.  There are programs that can do a lossless rotate which is a better solution in the long run if you don't want to just edit the metadata.

Comment: While this is not respecting the "keep the **orientation tag**" literally, this was exactly what I needed here (and meets the **purpose** of the question), so +1 from me! For my case the "destructive re-compress" is fully acceptable as the images are downsized and further compressed in a second step (think of "thumbnailing"; I keep the original images in a separate place). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is an option in XnView MP to reset all exif rotation information. 
It can be found in the menu
Tools > Jpeg Lossless transformation > Reset EXIF orientation field