# Get-ChildItem Doesn't Work With Include

Tags: powershell, wildcard, glob

[image]

Example I am following:

```
Get-ChildItem c:\scripts\*.* -include *.txt,*.log
```

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176841.aspx

What gives? Why don't I get back a list of my test.txt files when I try to use include?

As a side note, what is `c:\scripts\*.*`. It seems to be saying include a file with any name that has any format. But isn't that specified in the include? Anyway, more interested in why my seemingly basic code doesn't work.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

From [the help file (`Get-Help Get-ChildItem`)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem):

> The Include parameter is effective **only when either the command includes the *Recurse* parameter or the path leads to the contents of a directory**, such as C:\Windows*, where the wildcard character specifies the contents of the C:\Windows directory.

```
Get-ChildItem c:\pstest\*.* -include *.txt
```

or

```
Get-ChildItem c:\pstest -recurse -include *.txt
```

or better yet: use the `-Filter` parameter instead of `-Include`:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\pstest -Filter *.txt
```

Comment: Thank you, both of those work, but I am not following why I need " \*.\* " when I am already looking for filtered files in `pstest` (or whatever dir), seems redundant (though I am sure I am missing something).

Comment: @VSO in that case you should be using `-Filter`, not `-Include` (see update)

Comment: Alright, thanks, I will look at the differences between the two.

Comment: This is completely broken. Literally calling Get-ChildItem on '*' (i.e. the current directory) and the -Include pattern is not matched. Worse, the -Exclude pattern is not matched either. It just doesn't work.  Using -Recurse doesn't work either, nor does it even make sense to use it, since I'm not trying to recurse... literally just trying to Get-ChildItem(s) of the current directory. -Filter is not a workaround, as I need to Include one pattern while simultaneously excluding another. It's just non-functional.

Comment: "The implementation of -Include / -Exclude with Get-ChildItem is unintuitive and has pitfalls". No kidding. https://stackoverflow.com/a/38308796/88409

Answer (score 2):

you can do it simply too:

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\pstest\*.txt"
```

If you want to create more elaborate filters:

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\pstest\" -recurse -file | where {$_.Name -like "*hello*" -and $_.Name -notlike "*good by*"}
```

Comment: -Include requires the trailing wildcard.  If you want to do this and be OS-independent then you'd need to use join-path  

`$testdirectory = "C:\some\path\with\media\files" get-childitem -path ( join-path 
 $testdirectory  *)  -Include *.mp4,*.mkv,m4v,m4a`  

That safely puts the delimiter on the of the path so -Include will do it's thing properly.

Comment: I hate markdown, sorry for the repeated edits and failure to just put some damned linebreaks in there.