# Autotrim white border from scanned image with ImageMagick?

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I have ~200 scanned photos which I want to crop the white space out of. See example: [image]

Can someone provide me with the appropriate command line code to do this?... I have been trying to sort out the -trim and -fuzz options with no luck. NOT ALL images are same size (i.e. 4x6, 5x7, etc). All images were scanned/saved as jpg

Ideal scenario is a script where new trimmed photos are saved in one subdirectory.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using `-morphology` to remove the scan artifacts, trim, and then capture the resulting paging.

```
PAGE_OFFSET=$(convert TrmkF.jpg -morphology Dilate:3 Diamond:3,5 -fuzz 10% -trim -format '%wx%h%O' info:-)
```

The `$PAGE_OFFSET` variable should now have the *rough* location of the scanned photo. We can apply that value with the `-crop` command.

```
convert TrmkF.jpg -crop $PAGE_OFFSET output.jpg
```

[![output][1]][1]

**Edit**

A (powershell) batch script may look as simple as...

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\path\to\photos" -Filter *.jpg | 
Foreach-Object {
    $pageOffset = magick $_.FullName -morphology Dilate:3 Diamond:3,5 -fuzz 10% -trim -format '%xx%h%O' info:- | Out-String
    $output = $_.FullName + ".output.jpg"
    magick $_.FullName -crop $pageOffset +repage $output
}
```

*ymmv*
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8bSs.png

Comment: Thanks! Now since I want to do this as a batch, how would I edit the code to not specify a specific file 'TrmkF.jpg' and have it the code simply crop each and save in a subdirectory with 'imageXXX.jpg' ... ? Thanks!

Comment: What is your ImageMagick version and platform?

Comment: Just use a `for loop` to iterate over files. In linux/osx use [bash script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/162589), or [powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18848848/438117) in windows.

Comment: I am using powershell in windows but very novice... how would I incorporate a 'for' loop ... ? I am good with python but this is my first crack at ImageMagick

Comment: @fmw42 I am using the latest version of ImageMagick

Comment: Is that ImageMagick 6 or ImageMagick 7? What platform? Please provide the full version number. You can do it with: convert -version or magick -version depending upon whether version 6 or 7, respectfully. Are all your images in one directory.

Comment: @fmw42 apologies, I did not know there was a difference in coding between 6 and 7. I am using Image Magick 7.0.6 with Q-16 bit

Comment: What platform? and what exact version of ImageMagick 7. try magick -version

Comment: Version: ImageMagick 7.0.6-0 Q16 x64 2017-06-11

Comment: Unfortunately the batch script does not work... it splits a singular photo in to pieces 16 pieces instead of simply cropping the white space out

Comment: Windows 10 64 bit.

Comment: Try adding +repage after the crop; that is ... -crop $pageOffset +repage $output

Comment: For IM 7, the proper syntax is just magick, not magick convert.  But it sounds like you are not getting the offsets part of your crop values, if you are getting lots of output images. Check the values that you are putting into the $pageOffset

Comment: convert: invalid argument for option '-crop': +repage @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/1206.

Comment: Try adding +repage after the crop; that is ... -crop $pageOffset +repage $output

Comment: See my comments above about using magick and not magick convert and also checking your $pageOffset values.

Comment: Yea, I have essentially copy/pasted the powershell batch code above and made the modifications as stated in comments... what values in pageOffset should I be editing? EDIT I am also still getting invalid argument for +repage

Comment: Not editing, but returning them so you can see what the values are. They should be of the form WxH+Xoff+Yoff. If they are missing +Xoff+Yoff, then that would account for getting multiple output images. Sorry I do not use Windows and do not know Powershell, but I understand the ImageMagick command.

Comment: Does Powershell allow you to echo or print to your CMD window the value of $pageOffset

Comment: Try replacing -format '%@' for -trim -format '%xx%h%g'.

Comment: I am trying to print $pageOffset, do not think it will work... Argh!

Comment: Try replacing -format '%@' for -trim -format '%xx%h%g'. I do not think '%xx%h%g' is correct. It should have been -trim -format "%wx%h%X%Y"

Comment: Alright so the image is not getting split into 8 or 16 parts, but now no cropping is being done...

Comment: Did you make my change above to use -format '%@' in place of -trim -format '%xx%h%g'? Or use -trim -format "%wx%h%X%Y". Do either work? If not then try one single image in your CMD window or Powershell as magick TrmkF.jpg -morphology Dilate:3 Diamond:3 -fuzz 20% -format "%@" info:  Then copy the crop values that are returned and put them into magick TrmkF.jpg -crop cropvals +repage result.jpg Replace cropvals with the actual values you get, which  should be of the form WxH+X+Y. If this works, then something is wrong with your Powershell script.

Answer (score 1):

I've found that the above gives bad results, I think the formatting is different on MacOS or something so sharing the success story here. I have exactly this same issue - hundreds of scanned photos with some blotches in the white ruining the auto trim function.

I just modified parameters from the other individual's answer and got amazing results using this:

1. `cd` into your folder of images
2. `mkdir ../done`
3. v

```
echo "$f";\
size=$(magick "$f" -bordercolor White -border 10x10 \
-morphology Dilate:5 Diamond:5,7 -fuzz 5% -trim \
-format "%wx%h%O" info:-); \
echo $size; \
magick "$f" -bordercolor White -border 10x10 -crop $size +repage "../done/$f"; done;
```