# Powershell, Rename a directory after parsing and switching strings of its name

Tags: powershell, foreach, split, get-childitem, rename-item-cmdlet

So I am trying to rename several level1-subfolders from something like "xy_1234" to "1234_xy". So far I've achieved to split the strings into variables, build the new directory-name and rename the directory, but I'm completely failing, when trying to automate the process within a for-loop. Please help.

```
Get-Item $Path | ForEach ( $a, $b = $Path.split('_') | Rename-Item -NewName { $b + ('_') + $a})
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loop through files in a directory using PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18847145/loop-through-files-in-a-directory-using-powershell)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think several subfolders should be caught with a GCI
taking the  "xy_1234" to "1234_xy" literal:

```
Get-ChildItem $Path -Dir | Where-Object Name -match '^([a-z]+)_(\d+)$' |
    Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name.Split('_')[1,0] -join ('_')} -WhatIf
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Get-Item $Path | Rename-Item -NewName { 
  $tokens = $_.Name -split '_'         # split the name into tokens
  '{0}_{1}' -f $tokens[1], $tokens[0]  # output with tokens swapped
} -WhatIf
```

`-WhatIf` previews the operation.

As you can see, you can do the parsing as part of the script block passed to `Rename-Item`'s `-NewName` parameter.

Since `-NewName` only expects the item's file or directory new *name* (as opposed to the full path), `$_.Name` is parsed and a transformation of it is (implicitly) output.

Here's a more succinct formulation, inspired by a tip from [LotPings](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6811411/lotpings):

```
Get-Item $Path | Rename-Item -NewName { -join ($_.Name -split '(_)')[-1, 1, 0] }
```

This relies on PowerShell's ability to slice an array by specifying an *array (list)* of indices: `-1, 1, 0` effectively reverses the elements of the array that `$_.Name -split '(_)'` returns - note the `(...)` around `_`, which ensures that instances of `_` are included in the array of tokens returned; the unary form of the `-join` operator then concatenates the reversed array's elements.

---

Note: I'm assuming that `$Path` contains a wildcard expression that matches only the directories of interest.

If you need to be explicit about matching directories only, use `Get-ChildItem` with the
`-Directory` switch:

```
Get-ChildItem $Path -Directory
```

With a wildcard pattern specifically matching the sample name from your question:

```
Get-ChildItem [a-z][a-z]_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] -Directory
```